# How to set two users to chat together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want that if a user has ordered a meal, he can talk to the meal provider... and vice versa...
Users can provide meals and order meals too, like on air bnb you can be a guest or a host (or both)

Exemples:

1. Lets say we have Bob(*buyer*) who orders a meal from John(*maker*) I want that John and Bob can chat together
2. John(*buyer*) orders a meal from Mike(*maker*), John and Mike can chat together.

**conversations/index.html.erb**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to user.full_name , conversations_path(user_id: user), remote: true, method: :post %>
 <% end %>
```

**user.rb** (I have doubt in this model...)

```
  has_many :meals #Meals that the user offers
  has_many :received_orders, class_name: "Order" #The user receive an order
  has_many :placed_orders, through: :meals, class_name: "Order" #The user order a meal
  has_many :prepared_orders, through: :received_orders, class_name: "Meal", source: :meal #The user has prepared the order

  ####maybe this way below....TODO
  # has_many :meals
  # has_many :orders_as_a_customer, class_name: "Order"# same as: has_many :orders
  # has_many :orders_as_a_seller, through: :orders_as_a_customer, class_name: "Meal", source: :meal
  # has_many :orders, through: :meals
```

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :calculate_price
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :meal

  has_many :notifications, as: :topic

  monetize :amount_cents, as: :amount

  def payment
    self.payment_status = true
    self.save
  end

  def calculate_price
    self.amount = (self.quantity * meal.price)
  end
end
```

**Well I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.nopio.com/blog/rails-real-time-chat-application-part-1/) to create my chat, and I bet it's possible to adjust to my app to it...**

**conversation.rb**

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: "User"

  validates :sender_id, uniqueness: { scope: :recipient_id }

  scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do
    where(sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id).or(
      where(sender_id: recipient_id, recipient_id: sender_id)
    )
  end

  def self.get(sender_id, recipient_id)
    conversation = between(sender_id, recipient_id).first
    return conversation if conversation.present?

    create(sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id)
  end

  def opposed_user(user)
    user == recipient ? sender : recipient
  end
end
```

**conversations_controller.rb**

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @conversation = Conversation.get(current_user.id, params[:user_id])

    add_to_conversations unless conversated?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def index
    session[:conversations] ||= []
    @users = User.all.where.not(id: current_user)
    @conversations = Conversation.includes(:recipient, :messages).find(session[:conversations])
  end

  def close
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])

    session[:conversations].delete(@conversation.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def add_to_conversations
    session[:conversations] ||= []
    session[:conversations] << @conversation.id
  end

  def conversated?
    session[:conversations].include?(@conversation.id)
  end
end
```

my actual **schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170629192651) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "attachinary_files", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "attachinariable_type"
    t.integer  "attachinariable_id"
    t.string   "scope"
    t.string   "public_id"
    t.string   "version"
    t.integer  "width"
    t.integer  "height"
    t.string   "format"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.index ["attachinariable_type", "attachinariable_id", "scope"], name: "by_scoped_parent", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "conversations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_conversations_on_order_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["recipient_id", "sender_id"], name: "index_conversations_on_recipient_id_and_sender_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "meal_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["meal_id"], name: "index_ingredients_on_meal_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "meals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "menu_name"
    t.integer  "portion"
    t.date     "availability"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "images"
    t.string   "location"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_meals_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "conversation_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.index ["conversation_id"], name: "index_messages_on_conversation_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_messages_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "read",       default: false
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "topic_type"
    t.integer  "topic_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_notifications_on_order_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["topic_type", "topic_id"], name: "index_notifications_on_topic_type_and_topic_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_notifications_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "message"
    t.boolean  "payment_status", default: false
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "meal_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.integer  "amount_cents",   default: 0,     null: false
    t.json     "payment"
    t.index ["meal_id"], name: "index_orders_on_meal_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.integer  "meal_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["meal_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_meal_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "facebook_picture_url"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "token"
    t.datetime "token_expiry"
    t.string   "nickname"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "conversations", "orders"
  add_foreign_key "meals", "users"
  add_foreign_key "messages", "conversations"
  add_foreign_key "messages", "users"
  add_foreign_key "notifications", "orders"
  add_foreign_key "notifications", "users"
  add_foreign_key "orders", "meals"
  add_foreign_key "orders", "users"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "meals"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "users"
end
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of order model ?

Comment: Do you want to make so that each user should see only users, which may chat with him/her?

Comment: yes that's what i want :)

Comment: @mark order in common means ? user should common order in any received_orders or placed_orders or prepared_orders in common ?

Comment: User should see users, which ordered current user's meal?

Comment: Maybe it's here where I am going wrong...
Lets say with have Bob who order a meal to John
I want that John and Bob can chat together

Comment: Does that mean John is `Maker` who makes meals and Bob is a `Customer` who places an `Order` for a `Meal` from Bob?

Comment: That's it yes !

Comment: I think, simplest way in your situation will be expand your Order model with `seller_id` and `customer_id` and create a scope for User like this:
`scope :available_for_chat, -> current_user { joins(:orders).where(orders: { seller_id: current_user.id }) }`
I have no ability to test it right now, but may be you'll see the way )

Answer (score 0):

Concluding from the comments, you'd need to have different models. Here are the ones that make sense to me:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :meals
  has_many :orders
  has_many :sent_messages, :class => 'ChatMessage', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_messages, :class => 'ChatMessage', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
end

class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :order_item
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
end

class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  has_one :meal
end

class ChatMessage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, :class => 'User'
  belongs_to :receiver, :class => 'User'
end
```

Comment: I don't have sellers and customers only users that can be both... Like on air bnb you can be a guest or an host..

Comment: Customer and Seller will be exemplars of User model.
Your Order.rb will be seems like that
`belongs_to :customer, foreign_key: :customer_id, class_name: 'User'` and `belongs_to :seller, foreign_key: :seller_id, class_name: 'User'`

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure to get it... Shall I create two new models? `customer` and `seller` ?

Comment: could be, but customers and sellers in different models seems more apt in your use case. Plus the queries joining customers, sellers and orders would be a bit easier. And I really think you'd need order_items.

Comment: I am afraid that if I add the two models you suggest the rest of my app won't work anymore... or I have to re do all...

Comment: I have changed the answer to use a single User model. Hope this helps :)