# How can I translate a SQL request into Rails Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to translate SQL into Rails query with this [site](http://www.scuttle.io/) but it says:

`Scuttle parser error, check your SQL syntax.`

I am sorry but I don't really know how to write SQL request... so I've no idea where I am wrong...
Btw if  anyone knows how to write this as a rails query I'd be very happy

```
SELECT users.*
FROM orders inner 
JOIN meals ON orders.meal_id == meals.id inner 
JOIN users ON users.id = meals.user_id
WHERE order.user_id = current_user.id
```

### EDIT

Maybe the request is wrong... my question is related to my [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826591/how-to-set-two-users-to-chat-together/)
I've been suggested to sort my users with a query...

In this app a user can suggest a `meal`and order a `meal`through `order`.

I want that if a `user`has ordered a `meal`, he can start a `conversation`with the `user`he has purchased from.

Also that `user`who has purchased a `meal`can start a `conversation`with the `user`he has purchased from.

So in the `conversations`table I have the `order_id` (sorry it's not on the drawing).

[image]

Comment: Why are you writing `inner` on a separate line from `join`?  Are you intending for that to be an alias?  It may not be an issue for the compiler, but it's extremely confusing for whoever has to maintain that.

Comment: There's a typo: it should be `where orders.user_id = current_user.id`.

Comment: @Siyual it's because It's the first time I try to write it...

Comment: Try the following : `User.includes(:orders).where(orders: { user_id: current_user.id })` ; Also, this looks like Order `belongs_to :user` and User `has_many :orders`. If so, you can simply do `current_user.orders` to get all orders having `user_id` equal to `current_user.id`

Comment: @mark - Try adding aliases to the tables, somehow it worked for me. The end result was horrible though. But might be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to understand - **[Active Record Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)**

Not sure,  if Scuttle does resolve queries with joins or without aliases.

1. I changed it to older joins

   ```
   SELECT users.*
   FROM orders, meals, users
   where  orders.meal_id = meals.id  
   and users.id = meals.user_id
   and orders.user_id = current_user.id;
   ```

   It gives me

   ```
   User.select(User.arel_table[Arel.star]).where(
     Order.arel_table[:meal_id].eq(Meal.arel_table[:id]).and(
       User.arel_table[:id].eq(Meal.arel_table[:user_id]).and(
         Order.arel_table[:user_id].eq(CurrentUser.arel_table[:id])
       )
     )
   )
   ```

   When using `Arel Helpers`

   ```
   User.select(User[Arel.star]).where(
     Order[:meal_id].eq(Meal[:id]).and(
       User[:id].eq(Meal[:user_id]).and(Order[:user_id].eq(CurrentUser[:id]))
     )
   )
   ```
2. Your syntax

   ```
   SELECT u.*
   FROM orders o 
   JOIN meals m ON o.meal_id = m.id  
   JOIN users u ON u.id = m.user_id
   WHERE o.user_id = current_user.id ;
   ```

   gave -

   ```
   Order.select(U.arel_table[Arel.star]).where(
      O.arel_table[:user_id].eq(CurrentUser.arel_table[:id])
    ).joins(
      Order.arel_table.join(Meal.arel_table).on(O.arel_table[:meal_id].eq(M.arel_table[:id])).join_sources
    ).joins(
      Order.arel_table.join(User.arel_table).on(U.arel_table[:id].eq(M.arel_table[:user_id])).join_sources
   )
   ```

   when using `Arel Helpers`

   ```
   Order.select(U[Arel.star]).where(O[:user_id].eq(CurrentUser[:id])).joins(
     Order.arel_table.join(Meal.arel_table).on(O[:meal_id].eq(M[:id])).join_sources
   ).joins(
     Order.arel_table.join(User.arel_table).on(U[:id].eq(M[:user_id])).join_sources
   )
   ```

ps - I will never think of using this tool, it looks like it will work for a very specific set or maybe I have too less information on using it.

Comment: So could this be something like this? `@users = User.select(User.all.where('order.meal_id =, meal.id')) && (('user.id =, meal.user_id') && ("order.user_id = , current_user.id")))`

Comment: Well I accepted the answer because it helped a lot, still haven't foxed it but I on my way I guess ! Thanks :)